# Issue geting php value with Ajax request

Tags: php, ajax

I'm having issues with PHP and Ajax:
I want to make a simple page that shows your ping to google, so I tried this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var ping = <?php
        $ip =   "8.8.8.8";
        exec("ping -n 1 $ip", $output, $status);
        if(isset($output)){echo $output[2][37] . $output[2][38];}
        $output = array();
    ?>;
    document.getElementById("ping").innerHTML = ping;
},100)
```

It didn't work (i guess the php doesn't actualize), so I tried to call the php through ajax (i'm very new with ajax):
HTML:

```
<p id="ping"></p>
<script>
setInterval(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'ping.php',
        success: function(data){
            document.getElementById("ping").innerHTML = data;
        },
    });
},100)
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
function ping(){
    $ip =   "8.8.8.8";
    exec("ping -n 1 $ip", $output, $status);
    if(isset($output)){echo $output[2][37] . $output[2][38];}
}
?>
```

Nothing shows up.
What am I doing wrong?
(Sorry if I made any english mistakes)
Thanks

Comment: Just to help you out on why the first example didn't work: PHP executes server side (to generate html) before the client gets that html. JS happens on the client after they get the generated html from php. So once php echo'd out that one result into that `ping` js var... js would only ever use that value on each js interval. So your ajax method was the proper way to get 'fresh' data from php to use.

Comment: Side note: You MAY want to change `100` to `1000` (or even more). Because 1000 = 1 second interval. The other will be slamming the server 10 times per second, and each ajax call will then clamber over each other depending who returns quicker with results (since there are no promise chains here).

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! I kept the 100ms interval, I just did this to overcome the issue:
if(ping!=undefined){...}

Answer (score 1):

I think I just figured it out myself: I just removed the function() ping in the .PHP:

```
<?php

    $ip =   "8.8.8.8";
    exec("ping -n 1 $ip", $output, $status);
    if(isset($output)){echo $output[2][37] . $output[2][38];}

?>
```

Works great

Comment: you could have also "called" the function.